# For deploying a public-facing webapp, which between Testing and Stable to use some weeks before release?

Tags: debian, stability, support-cycle

Which do you recommend? Some POVs to consider:

- stability
- available packages
- life
- kernels
- or any other reasons?

[**note**] This question was originally a request for recommendation between Debian 5 "lenny" and Debian 6 "squeeze". I modified it to make it more generic.

Comment: I think we should close this as too localized, this won't be right in 5 years when the next debian is released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for Debian Testing:

- **life**: Official support for Debian releases end a year after a new one has been released. So if you go for Debian Stable, you only have a year from next release before needing to upgrade.
- **stability**: At the time of writing, the soon-to-be Debian 6 "squeeze" had ~20 RC bugs while then Debian 5 "lenny" had a whooping ~900 RC bugs (but [don't read too much into it](http://ask.debian.net/questions/why-are-there-more-rc-bugs-in-lenny-than-in-squeeze)).
- **packages**: Each release of Debian has more packages than the last. Note that sometimes some packages are removed from a release. Reasons may include death of software, stability, security, ...
- **kernels**: More often than not, you want a newer kernel, if not for nothing but improved hardware support.